# phpMyAdmin error call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin I have a white page and there is an error in the apache2 log's:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php:245\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php(321): PMA_fatalError('The [a@./url.ph...')\n#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(298): PMA_warnMissingExtension('json', true)\n#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(12): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 245

I search on the web and I see there is a problem with the php-mbstring, so I installed it but not fix the problem. I have also reinstall completely php, mysql and phpmyadmin...

Comment: did you try to give 777 persmission to php/session folder ?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin and PHP versions are you using?

Comment: I encountered the same problem. PhpMyAdmin stopped working. I remembered that I had made a mistake a few days ago running `sudo chmod 775 /` (I mistyped). I thought that I had fixed it with a Timeshift-restore but the problem, evidently, wasn't solved. The solution suggested by  @OussemaAroua worked for me. `chmod 777 /var/lib/php/sessions` (you can find the session folder path in the phpinfo() file - look for session.save_path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) open the file : `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php`

2) Add the below lines instead of 224-229

```
  if (!function_exists('__')) {
          include_once GETTEXT_INC;
              if (defined(GETTEXT_INC)) {
                 include_once GETTEXT_INC;
               } else {
                  include_once './libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc';
               }
   }
```

Comment: Problem fix but there is a new problem, I have an error in the page:
The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.